# How to integrate GitHub and Eclipse in 2022?

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I apologize in advance for my ignorance.

I'm trying to figure out how to import a repository from GitHub into Eclipse.

First, I go to Import > Git > Projects from Git > Clone URI. I enter in the location of the repository, and under "Authentication" I type in my GitHub username and password. When I click "Next", it asks for my username and password again. It does this three times before giving me this error message:

> An error occurred when trying to contact [repository URL]. See the Error Log for more details
>
> Possible reasons:
>
> - Incorrect URL
> - No newtork connection (e.g. wrong proxy settings)
> - SSL host could not be verified (set http.sslVerify=false in Git configuration)

The message given in the Error Log is simply the repository URL followed by "not authorized".

I have also tried using SSH instead of HTTPS, with no success.

Edit: here's the full stack trace from the error log:

```
org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$9.run(SourceBranchPage.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/DGarrard2/piecepack.git: not authorized
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:170)
```

Comment: github does not support username/password authentication anymore. I think the easiest way to do it (through I haven't used eclipse in a while) is that you clone the project _outside of eclipse_ with your favorite git client.... or `git` itself (with ssh or https with tokens as transport) and then import it into eclipse as an existing project.

Comment: "See the Error Log for more details" What does the error log say?

Comment: @eftshift0: you should be able to generate a GitHub token as usual (using browser) and then paste the token in as if it were a password, since it *is* a password...

Comment: Oh, I C.... the wonders of using ssh :-) (I do not get to see this).